# XSL namespace issue

Tags: xslt, xsd, xslt-1.0

I have an XSL that is transforming one XSD into another XSD that has slightly different formatting. (Basically, the target file will be normalized). The other major difference in the target is adding a default namespace and a target namespace. I'm having trouble actually getting the namespace in. Here is a snippet of my XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <xsl:variable name="Unions" select="'Yes'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="myname" select="//Table/Name"/>
    <xsl:variable name="namespace" select="concat('http://mynamespace/', $myname)"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="xsd:schema" namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="$namespace"

      <xsl:attribute name="targetNamespace">
        <xsl:value-of select="$namespace"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="elementFormDefault">qualified</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="attributeFormDefault">unqualified</xsl:attribute>
...
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And this is what I'm getting:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://mynamespace/somename" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="">
...
</xsd:schema>
```

And xmlns="$namespace" is tagged on to every child node. I'm no absolute expert on XSLT. I have not had to develop it myself because BizTalk maps generate all of it for you, but this XSL was more complex than I could get BizTalk maps to handle.

Oh, and I'm limited to XSLT 1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generating namespace nodes with dynamically generated values is something XSLT 1 can't really do. XSLT 2 adds `xsl:namespace` specifically to construct such things.

You said you are stuck at XSLT 1. Do you have EXSLT or any other extension namespace available that gives you the node-set() extension? If so you can go

```
 <xsl:template match="/">

 <xsl:variable name="x">
 <xsl:element name="x" namespace="{$namespace}">
   <xsl:element name="xsd:schema" namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   ....
 </xsl:variable>
 <xsl:copy-of select="xx:node-set($x)/*/*"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Creating a spurious element `<x>` in the desired namespace, this forces the namespace node on to its child `xs:schema` element which you can extract if you have a node-set extension function.

Comment: I will look into it and see if EXSLT is an option. And once I find out if it is an option, I will look to see if I can convince people in my organization to feel comfortable with it. If not, then is the short answer, that this is impossible with my limitations?

Comment: I don't think it is possible in one pass in xslt 1 without an extension function. What you can do in pure xslt1 is use one stylesheet that figures out the target namespace and then writes out a _stylesheet_ in which that namespace is a literal constant then apply the generated stylesheet.